Django trying to encrypt fields when creating database and retrieveing them in decrypted form, how can I achieve this?
I am working on a django project where I need to store data inside some columns in an encrypted format and decrypt it on the fly whenever querying the said data. I have managed to encrypt the data while storing using cryptography-Fernet.
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(self.first_name, str):
            self.first_name = cipher_suite.encrypt(self.first_name.encode())
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

but When I am trying to retrieve the data, I am not able to fetch it in a decrypted format, As I do not know which method to override to achieve this result. What can I do to make this work?
I have tried creating a property at django model But I am unable to trigger it, as I am not aware on how to trigger a model property in django models when a queryset is being executed. This is the property in question.
@property
    def enc_first_name(self):
        if self.first_name:
            val = cipher_suite.decrypt(self.first_name).decode()
            return val
        return self.first_name

Alternate solutions I tried, because our project is on python 3.10 and django 5.0, I am unable to use django-cryptography library which would have reduced complexity of this task tremendously. Also I have been recommended to use microsoft-presidio library but that only seems to work on text data directly. I have tried passing it variables encrypt as well as anonymize but it does not seem to work. Any Help is appreciated.

You cannot use a property to query the database. But, you can access the value by calling obj.enc_first_name after querying.

You can use a Serializer to do the decryption if you're using django-rest-framework.

We are using django-rest-framework, problem is serializer are not used in all of the APIs, that's why I thought to just override the model read directly to avoid changes in APIs.

When you run .get() or .filter the orm just returns an instance or a list of instances of the Model. But it won't automatically trigger the property. To do that you will have to access it using instance.property.
